# Is diluting filter concentrate after the brew the same as brewing with the additional water?

Tags: brewing-process, aeropress, extraction

Recently moved from a Clever Drip coffee maker to an Aeropress. I brew using a 60g to 1 ltr ratio often brewing 24g yielding 400ml on the clever drip and 12g to 200ml on the Aeropress. If I am brewing for 3 people should I brew 3 batches 12g/200ml or something like 36g/150ml and dilute the concetrate with 450ml of water?

TLDR: Is diluting filter concentrate after the brew the same as brewing with the additional water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not the same. The brew ratio is important to extract the right amount of solubles from the coffee, ideally all the pleasant ones and only few of the unpleasant ones.

If you brew with less water, you'll dissolve less of the coffee's goodness, and diluting that will lead to a thin coffee compared to a correctly brewed one.

Conversely, if you brew with too much water, you'll extract bitter substances you won't like, so if you like a thinner coffe (like an americano) it's best to brew normally and then dilute.

Unfortunately, the Aeropress is not really suitable to serve multiple guests.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. This is really clear